# problems with $watch function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm not really sure about this issue but it seems that sometimes when I activate $watch for a function then it doesn't work.
for example I have this simple service

```
angular.module('sp-app').factory('mediaSources', function() {
    var storages = [];
    return {
        addStorage: function(storage) {
            storages.push(storage);

        },
        getStorages: function() {
            return storages;
        }

    }

});
```

and when I watch getStorage method in order to update my view it doesn't call change callback or calls only at initialization stage

```
$scope.$watch(function($scope) {            
        return mediaSources.getStorages();
    }, function() {     
        console.log('call')
    });
```

and I can only track changes by watching length property of returned array

`return mediaSources.getStorages().length;`
and I wonder because I have written similar think somewhere else within my application and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If i interpret what you are trying to do, you should not need to set a watch on something like this, you can just use a factory like so :

```
angular.module('app').factory('mediaSources', function(){
     var storages = {};

     storages.list = [];

     storages.add = function(message){
         storages.list.push(message);
     };

     return storages;
});
```

then in the controller you want to receive/update the data to for instance, you would do

```
 $scope.myControllerVar = mediaSources.list;
```

No need to watch over it, it should update for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set up watcher with [equality flag](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) as the third argument:

```
$scope.$watch(function($scope) {
    return mediaSources.getStorages();
}, function() {
    console.log('call');
}, true);
```

Comment: and how would you explain that it sometimes work for the other components?